# Describe a REST resource as in the process of being moved

Tags: rest, bitcoin, atomic, blockchain

In my application, I currently use a REST resource which points to something on the Bitcoin blockchain:

```
/channels/:pubkey/pay/:txid/:vout
```

The `txid` and `vout` path parameter comprise the "pointer" to a something in the Blockchain: the source of funds. In order to pay the server (from the source of funds), the client (`pubkey`) PUTs a payment on the resource, where the payment contains a signature over the `txid`/`vout` pair in question (plus some other stuff).

However, when the server needs to make use of the value it has received so far from the client, it has to move the above `txid`/`vout` pair on the blockchain, and there is a period in which it is necessary that the client provide payments for both `txid`/`vout` pairs, because the move is not final until the transaction is embedded in the blockchain (which takes roughly an hour or two). The move is atomic, so it will either fail or succeed, but we don't know what will happen yet, so two payments (using both resources) is required in the interim.

So, if (during the transitional period) the PUT request in question is performed on both resources, everything is fine, and payments can flow as normal. Otherwise, we need to pause payments while the underlying resource has settled.

So I guess I'm looking for a RESTful way to describe an atomic resource move that takes a few hours to complete. Is there a convenient way to handle this in a RESTful manner? Or do I need to hide this complexity in my application protocol?

Comment: Why does the client have to perform the request on both resources?

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde You made me realize my original explanation was insufficient, and I've rewritten it almost entirely to describe the problem in question.

Comment: There's no way to perform two requests in HTTP and regard them as a single transaction. In HTTP, the request is the transaction. I propose you use POST requests and pass the txid and vout parameters (both pairs if necessary) in the body and leave them out of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

No resource exists in two places at once. You have two URLs, therefore you have two resources. These resources may represent the same "something" on the blockchain, but the client doesn't know that.

If the resource has moved, it should indicate that by returning a `301 Moved Permanently` response code, with a `Location` header indicating the new URL. Any request that the client tries at that time should be retried on the new URL.

The client is not aware of the "new" location until it is told using this response code, and your API shouldn't reflect the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Using a temporary redirect on the resource while the transaction is in progress but unfinished, and changing this to a permanent redirect when the transaction is done, should have the desired effect (making sure the server receives the necessary data for both resources), although the same data from the redirected request is not resubmitted to the new resource, but must be recalculated (using the appropriate `txid` and `vout` parameters) for the resource to which we redirect.

I'm not entirely sure if there are appropriate 3xx HTTP status codes that specify that the request body must be recreated to fit the particular resource that is redirected to (ie. we're not just routing the same request to a different resource).